# Weblogic, beans aren't found by Spring

Tags: spring, tomcat, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

We have a web application that uses Spring 3. And we have to migrate it from Tomcat 7 to Weblogic 10.

The structure of this application is:

- a core module, which contains all the application logic. This module is packaged as a jar.
- a web module, which defines all the web services. This module includes the previous one as a dependency and uses its beans by including the core-module context in the 'contextConfigLocation' param.

I'm using maven and this is how the dependency is defined in the web-module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>${environment}</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The application worked fine in tomcat, but it can't be deploied in Weblogic since Spring can't create any bean that depends on beans in core-module.jar. The error is always the same for all the beans comming from core-module:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xxxBean' is defined
```

'xxxBean' is any of the bean defined in core-module.jar. If I delete the ref to avoid the problem with that bean, the next referenced bean will provoke the error again. I mean Spring finds all the beans defined in web-module itself, but none defined in core-module.

In the trace of the error, I can see that weblogic is using this:

```
com.oracle.weblogic.wsee.wrapper.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized
```

so the problem may be related to the wrapper that Weblogic introduces for spring applications.

Any idea about the configuration that can fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have bean named xxxBean? Maybe you just accidentally left some comment or something like that. Try to search you deployment for that string.

Comment: No, it's a fictitious name. I used it because the problem happens with any bean of the application. If I comment a bean, the problem occurrs with the next referenced bean.

Comment: How are you defining the dependency betwen web module and core?

Comment: I'm using maven, I add the definition of this in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I mean is your web service in a WAR and the core-module is in WEB-INF/lib of that WAR? Or is your web service in a JAR

Comment: Right, the web service is in a WAR and the core-module is WEB-INF/lib of that war. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem was related to how the different xml files were defined in the web.xml. The original configuration, which was working fine in tomcat, was:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:core-context.xml
        classpath:spring-web-security.xml 
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

and the new one:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:core-context.xml,classpath:spring-web-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

They have to be declared comma-separated instead of with new lines. Since weblogic didn't complain about the format of the xml, to find the problem was a bit complicated. I hope this can avoid people to spend time with this kind of migrations. Regards and thanks!!

Comment: In my case, the cause was using `**` instead of directory name. I replaced `classpath:**/*-context.xml` with `classpath:spring/*-context.xml`

Answer (score 0):

A `contextConfigLocation` of `classpath:core-module-applicationContext.xml` or whatever the actual file is called should work.

Can you try defining a weblogic.xml into the WEB-INF/ with this content

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <weblogic-web-app
 xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic- web-app.xsd">
     <container-descriptor>
         <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
      </container-descriptor>
 </weblogic-web-app>`

Modify it for Weblogic 10, essentially we want to set `prefer-web-inf-classes` to true

Comment: I've tried this, but same problem :-( By the way, the weblogic documentation says that the value specified in the Administration Console will take precedence over a value set manually, but I didn't find where I can check it in the console. Thanks

Comment: did u try all combinations: `classpath*:appcontext.xml` or `classpath:**/appcontext.xml` etc?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Finally, this mornig I found the problem. I had different appliction context files, one for core beans and another one for spring security. I've had to separate their definition with commas, in tomcat they was separated by a new line. The problem was that the error of weblogic wasn't related to the real problem. I'll add it to the question. Thanks a lot!!